# Start a browser with your own custom title from command line?

Tags: webbrowser-control, command-line-arguments

From a shell command line:

```
start "title" program
```

will start a session with a your custom "title"

however, when starting a browser, the "title" doesnt show up.

Does anyone know the syntax to make the "title" be on top of the browser title?

ref: http://ss64.com/nt/start.html

Answer (score 0):

From a shell, there's simply no way to change the title of the browser's windows. You would need to use the Win32 API to do that (e.g., by using a window hook to modify the behavior of the browser), but this is pretty complex to do. An alternative would be to develop an extension/add-on for the browser, but this means that you would need to write an add-on for each browser you need to support, and to have these extensions installed in the browser.